# Installing Office Customizations System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I'm trying to deploy my Outlook Add-In to a Windows 10 Machine, but I always get this error after installation:

```
Name: 
From: file:///C:/Users/Public/MycompanyOutlookAddIn.vsto

************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.VSTOEENativeMethods.GetValidCompatibleFramework(String compatibleFrameworkXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.CompatibleFrameworksValidation.ParseFirstValidFramework(String compatibleFrameworksXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.OfficeAddInDeploymentManager.OnAddInManifestsDownloaded(AddInManifestsDownloadedArgs args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.RaiseOnAddInManifestsDownloadedEvent(IClickOnceAddInInstaller addInInstaller, Uri deploymentManifestUri, AddInInstallationStatus addinSolutionState, String productName, String deploymentManifestXml, String applicationManifestXml, String hostManifestXml, String logFilePath, String version, Uri supportUri)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```

Some questions from years ago suggested that the path was too long, so I changed mine to the `Public` directory but I still get this error.

Another thing that I tried was running this:

```
rundll32 %windir%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache
```

but after reinstalling I get the same error.

Weird thing is that When I deploy to Windows 7 machines it works flawlessy. The Add-In was developed without much problems in Windows 8.1. I only get this error on Windows 10. Could somebody please tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must install the extension **Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime**

[Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48217)

Comment: This is indeed my solution. MS really should make it more obvious what the stacktrace/error means!